# Controlling 0-5V from 0-3.3V PWM pin and 5V power

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, dc, pwm, basic

What I have is I think a standard problem in home electronics but I can't wrap my head around it. I'd like to control an IKEA light chain from an ESP32 board. The chain is basically a set of LED diodes connected parallelly. The power cannot be sourced from the pin itself because it exceeds board limitation of 40mA draw (the lights consume 0.72W which is ~144mA at 5V). I want to shift somewhat linearly 0-3.3V from the pin to 0-5V to the lights to turn them on/off and dim.

At first I tried tried using a [BC337](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bc337-d.pdf) NPN transistor but I'm only getting 2.6V max.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPfewB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've also tried using an [L293DNE](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293.pdf) motor driver but the max voltage drops to 2.7V under load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF2o3B.png)</sup>

1. What are some other ways to do it? I've read somewhere that a MOSFET transistor might work.
2. How can I find a proper transistor and calculate the emitted voltage based on values from its specification.
3. Is there a standard name for what I'm trying to achieve? I'm basically looking for keywords here so I can find relevant information.

Comment: Well, an emitter-follower is not the way to go. Even if all the rest is right. (Which it probably isn't.) Can you provide a link to the specifications for the LED string?

Comment: They don't provide anything. There's only a sticker that says 5V DC, 24 x 0.03W. They are powered via USB connector but just connected straight to VCC/GND pins.

Comment: So they need a 5 VDC rail and there are 24 of the darned things. So 6 mA each LED, then. Or, as you say, 144 mA total for the string. That is very very doable with small signal BJTs. Just not as emitter followers. Where does the 3.3 V come in? I'm still confused about that. Is that what your ESP is limited to for its I/O pin max output voltage?

Comment: ESP32 can be powered with either 3.3V or 5V which is later regulated on board. I want to use a 5V input to power both ESP32 and the chain. The PWM-modulated 0-3.3V comes from the GPIO pin I'm controlling with code.

Comment: So it is regulated ***down*** to 3.3 V on the board, regardless. The I/O pins can only drive out 3.3 V, I take it. Try grounding the emitter of the NPN. Expect to use 1/20th of the 144 mA, or about 7.2 mA for the I/O pin, which from your wiring appears to be well within its capability. The resistor value should be about (3.3-0.9)/8mA or about a 270 Ohm resistor from the I/O pin to the NPN base pin. Attach the IKEA load between 5 V and the collector. See if that works.

Comment: just swap the BJT and the LEDs in your first diagram.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/293631/how-convert-a-3-3v-pwm-signal-to-a-5v-pwm-signal https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67775/driving-led-strip-from-microcontroller https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56093/how-to-use-a-3v-output-to-control-a-5v-relay

Comment: @dandavis that worked pretty well, 4.65V output :)

Comment: if you used an nchannel fet it would work even better, i use the irlz44n a lot for 3.3v switching of large loads.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This means that with a 5 volt drive level on GPI)18 the max voltage on the emitter is about 4.3 volts.

> *I want to shift somewhat linearly 0-3.3V from the pin to 0-5V to the
> lights*

Of course, if your supply voltage is 3.3 volts then, the maximum voltage you'll get on the emitter is 2.6 volts.

You should try using an op-amp and BJT circuit to adjust the current through the LED: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://circuitdigest.com/sites/default/files/inlineimages/u2/Op-Amp-With-MOSFET.png). The LED would connect between the supply and the drain of the MOSFET above. There's also this version that uses a MOSFET: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.analog.com/-/media/images/analog-dialogue/en/volume-48/number-2/articles/current-output-circuit-techniques-add-versatility/4804-2-fig05.jpg?la=en&imgver=1).

You should also be aware that most LEDs will fail if given too much voltage and that controlling the LED current is a more reliable method.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use PWM.
2. Connect the transistor in a common emitter configuration, with emitter connected to ground, base connected via a 4k7 resistor to GPIO, and collector collected to the cathode (-) of the LED light.

PWM is inherently linear no matter what the peak voltage is. Here you’re using a 3.3V PWM signal to control a switch that toggles a 5V load. 100% PWM will be equivalent to full brightness, 50% will be approximately half brightness, etc.

This will work as long as the LED light doesn’t include some fancy active drive circuitry, like a boost power converter. If it only included an active current source then the chances are it will work fine with PWM, perhaps only in a limited frequency range. You’ll have to experiment. Start with 1kHz PWM and go up if it misbehaves.